# UPBGE Actions Using Joystick Control

Tags: python, animation, game-engine, logic-bricks, actions

I am in the process of creating a playable character in UPBGE 0.36.1. I’m setting it up with a USB gamepad so that A) the character moves faster or slower according to how much the left analog stick is tilted, B) the character’s animations speed up and slow down based on the its linear velocity, and C) it’s set up to play tiptoe, walking, and running animations, also based on the character’s linear velocity.

I have two main questions:
1: I have the animation all set up, but I just need to know how to make it happen in the game so that the “run end” animation ends when the character stops running suddenly, and the “walk end” animation plays when the character stops walking suddenly. I have the tiptoe animation set to just blend with the idle animation, which looks pretty natural, since the legs don’t have very far to move.
2: I have found that the Action actuator’s “Blendin” setting doesn’t work when I have a property controlling the animation frame. Is there any workaround, with python or some other method, to make the animations blend?

I have attached the .blend file. If anyone has any advice, that is much appreciated.

Comment: You haven't actually attached the Blend file, but in any case I doubt there's anyone here who would be able to help as most of us here use the native version of Blender not the UPBGE version with the game engine in it which is maintained seperately.